# Specifying data type while importing from CSV into RethinkDB

Tags: json, csv, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I am using 'rethinkdb import' to import a CSV file where one of the fields is a valid JSON object. However, it seems like RethinkDB is encoding this field as a string since I am unable to use nested filters to query the data set.

How do I specify the data type of each field at import time or modify the assumed data type after the import is finished?

Comment: Do you know what field that will be JSON beforehand? Why not just parse it before inserting?

Comment: Yes, it's the same field for all the records. What do you mean by parsing it before inserting? I am using rethinkdb's import command for mass ingestion -- ingesting the records one by one will take forever.

Comment: My apologies. I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/importing/):

> JSON files are preferred to CSV files, as JSON can represent RethinkDB
>   documents fully. If you’re importing from a CSV file, you should
>   include a header row with the field names, or use the --no-header
>   option with the --custom-header option to specify the names.

```
rethinkdb import -f users.csv --format csv --table test.users --no-header \
    --custom-header id,username,email,password
```

> Values in CSV imports will always be imported as strings. If you want
>   to convert those fields after import to the number data type, run an
>   update query that does the conversion. An example runnable in the Data
>   Explorer:

```
r.table('tablename').update(function(doc) {
    return doc.merge({
        field1: doc('field1').coerceTo('number'),
        field2: doc('field2').coerceTo('number')
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you -- not sure how I missed the second part.

Comment: Hmm .. now getting this error from RethinkDB:

`Cannot coerce STRING to OBJECT.`

The documentation does not list string -> object as a valid coerce operation unfortunately.

https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/coerce_to/

Comment: @Alienfluid Ah, bummer. Maybe nested fields can be specified in the first step..? Just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: What format are the objects in? Are they JSON objects?
In that case you can use `field1: r.json(doc('field1'))` inside the mentioned merge command.